# Char array to hex string conversion - unexpected output

Tags: c++

I have a simple program converting dynamic char array to hex string representation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    int length = 2;
    char *buf = new char[length];
    buf[0] = 0xFC;
    buf[1] = 0x01;

    stringstream ss;
    ss << hex << setfill('0');
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (int) buf[i] << " ";
    }
    string mystr = ss.str();
    cout << mystr << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
fffffffc 01
```

Expected output:

```
fc 01
```

Why is this happening? What are those **ffffff** before **fc**? This happens only on certain bytes, as you can see the **0x01** is formatted correctly.

Comment: Removing the hex, fill, and width modifiers, and just sending `(int)buf[i]` to stdout will provide a pretty significant hint as to what is happening.

Comment: That is correct, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things you need to know to understand what's happening:

1. The first thing is that `char` can be either signed *or* unsigned, it's implementation (compiler) specific
2. When converting a small signed type to a large signed type (like e.g. a signed `char` to an `int`), they will be *sign extended*
3. How negative values are stored using the most common [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system, where the highest bit in a value defines if a value is negative (bit is set) or not (bit is clear)

What happens here is that `char` seems to be signed, and `0xfc` is considered a negative value, and when you convert `0xfc` to an `int` it will be sign-extended to `0xfffffffc`.

To solve it use explicitly `unsigned char` and convert to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3):

This is called "[sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension)".

`char` is a signed type, so 0xfc will become negative value if you force it in to a `char`.
Its decimal value is -4

When you cast it to `int`, it extends the sign bit to give you the same value.
(It happens here `(int) buf[i]`)

On your system, `int` is 4 bytes, so you get the extra bytes filled with `ff`.